# Magento get product

Tags: php, magento

I have a site into my Magento where I want to make a custom query.
My query is ok (I have tried it into phpmyadmin)

I have tried this code into my file .phtml

```
<?php
// fetch write database connection that is used in Mage_Core module
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$result = $db->query("select * from catalog_product_flat_1 WHERE short_description LIKE '%".$description_search."%' AND entity_id != ".$product_id." ;");
//After running  check whether data is available or not
if(!$result) {
  echo 'No data found';
}
else
{
//Here we are fetching the data
 echo('<p>here '.$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).'</p>');
 foreach ($result->fetchAll() as $row)
    {
        echo ('<p><br>Name: </p>');
    }
}
```

Into the foreach doesn't print anything  and the fetchAll is empty.
But if I make:

```
var_dump($result);
```

With this var_dump I have the object for example:

```
object(Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql)#631 (9) { ["_fetchMode":protected]=> int(2) ["_stmt":protected]=> object(PDOStatement)#572 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(130) "select * from catalog_product_flat_1 WHERE short_description LIKE '%Riferimento originale: TN-1700%' AND entity_id != 733536 ;" } ["_adapter":protected]=> object(Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)#14 (30) { ["_defaultStmtClass":protected]=> string(29) "Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql" ["_transactionLevel":protected]=> int(0) ["_connectionFlagsSet":protected]=> bool(true) ["_ddlCache":protected]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { ["eav_attribute"]=> array(17) { ["attribute_id"]=> array(14) { ["SCHEMA_NAME"]=> NULL....
```

How can I retrieve correctly my product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may below code work for you

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldtoFilter('short_description', array('like' =>'%Good Luck%'))
->addFieldtoFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => 404));
```

and then you can get field data like

```
foreach($collection as $row){
echo $row->getName();
}
```

Comment: return error into the select I have to retrieve data from catalog_product_flat_1